# Is it possible to specify a `stack.yaml` file for a haskell script?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Let's say I have the following script inside my haskell project directory:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver lts-12.5 script

-- some imports here

main :: IO ()
main = do
  -- some code here
```

I'd like to use the `stack.yaml` file that exists inside the project directory, in order to get the required packages, as I want to get them from a specific git commit instead of `lts-12.5`.

I've tried adding `--stack-yaml stack.yaml` after `--resolver lts-12.5` but I'm getting this warning when I run the script: `Ignoring override stack.yaml file for script command: stack.yaml`.

Is it possible to use my `stack.yaml` file for the script? or is it possible to specify the git commit from which I want to get the package (like using `location` with `commit` and `git` inside `stack.yaml`)?

Comment: I believe that if you use `stack runhaskell` instead of `stack script`, it will use a `stack.yaml` file. The primary purpose of `script` is to ensure the script *doesn’t* use `stack.yaml` so that it’s completely independent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this using custom snapshot files. For example, in `snapshot.yaml`:

```
resolver: ghc-8.4.3
name: has-acme-missiles
packages:
- acme-missiles-0.3
```

In `Main.hs`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env stack
-- stack --resolver snapshot.yaml script
import Acme.Missiles

main :: IO ()
main = launchMissiles
```

Results in:

```
$ ./Main.hs 
Nuclear launch detected.
```